# drag and drop mobile responsive image marker plugin for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I tried jquery plugin for drag and drop image marker. It is working on windows, but not working on the mobile device. Can anyone help me?

Javascript code is:

```
;(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {

'use strict';

// defining vars in the begining of every function to predict hoisting
// define vars separatelly to avoid mistakes with comas and semicolons
var pluginName = 'imageMarker';
var defaults = {drag_disabled: false};

function Plugin ( element, options ) {
  this.$element = $(element);
  this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
  this._defaults = defaults;
  this._name = pluginName;
  this._markers = [];
  this.$left_box = null;
  this.$right_box = null;
  this.$drag_box = null;
  this.init();
}

$.extend( Plugin.prototype, {
  init: function() {
    this.renderMarkup();
    this.bindListeners();
  },

  // preparing the markup for insertion into target element, using $ prefix for jquery objects
  // using BEM for class naming (block__element--modifier), control visual part with updating css
  renderMarkup: function() {
    var $container =                    $('<div class="image-marker-container"></div>');
    var $left_box_wrapper =             $('<div class="image-marker-container__box image-marker-container__box--left"></div>');

    // linking element for fast manipulation in future (adding markers, checking height), so no need for searching for element again
    var $left_box =  this.$left_box =   $('<div class="image-marker-container__box__content"></div>');
    var $right_box_wrapper =            $('<div class="image-marker-container__box image-marker-container__box--right"></div>');
    var $right_box = this.$right_box =  $('<div class="image-marker-container__box__content"></div>');
    var $image_box =                    $('<div class="image-marker-container__box image-marker-container__box--image"></div>');
    var $drag_box = this.$drag_box =    $('<div class="image-marker-container__box image-marker-container__box--drag"></div>');
    var $image =                        $('<img class="image-marker-container__img"/>');

    var onDrop = function(e, ui) {
      var dropped = ui.draggable;
      var $droppedOn = $(this).find('.image-marker-container__box__content');
      var marker = $.data(dropped[0],'marker');

      // prevent move if does not fit col
      if ($(this).height() < $droppedOn.height() + $(dropped).height()) return dropped.draggable('option', 'revert', true);

      // prevent move if same col
      if ($(this).hasClass('image-marker-container__box--left') && marker.col == 1) return dropped.draggable('option', 'revert', true);
      if (!$(this).hasClass('image-marker-container__box--left') && marker.col == 2) return dropped.draggable('option', 'revert', true);

      // add col id to marker obj 
      marker.col = $(this).hasClass('image-marker-container__box--left') ? 1 : 2;
      $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo($droppedOn);
    };

    $left_box_wrapper.append($left_box).droppable({accept: '.image-marker__text-box', drop: onDrop});;
    $right_box_wrapper.append($right_box).droppable({accept: '.image-marker__text-box', drop: onDrop});

    $image.attr('src', this.settings.src);
    $image_box.append($image).append($drag_box);

    // bundling the markup into vitrual container
    $container.append($left_box_wrapper).append($right_box_wrapper).append($image_box);

    // inserting virtual container as a last step regarding to performance issues (slow dom, reflow, repaint)
    this.$element.append($container);
  },

  // adding listeners for client to trigger plugin functions
  bindListeners: function() {
    this.$element.on('add_marker', (function(e, data) {

      this.addTextbox(data);
    }).bind(this)); // binding context to avoid closure in parent function (var self = this)
    this.$element.on('get_markers', (function(e, cb) 
    {
      // calling callback function with array of all markers added to image so client can save them, returning new array for keep data immutable from outside
      cb(Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this._markers));
    }).bind(this));
  },

  // adding text box
  addTextbox: function(marker) {

    // all manipulations with virtual element should be done before insertion regarding to performance issues
    var $text_box = $('<div class="image-marker__text-box"></div>');
    var $dot = $('<div class="image-marker__dot"></div>');
    var $line = $('<div class="image-marker__line"></div>');
    var $left_box = this.$left_box;
    var onDrag = function() {

          var text_box_offset = ($text_box.parent()[0] == $left_box[0]) ? ($text_box.parent().width() - 4) : 4;
          var x1 = $text_box.offset().left + text_box_offset;
          var x2 = $dot.offset().left + ($dot.width() / 2);
          var y1 = $text_box.offset().top + ($text_box.height() / 2);
          var y2 = $dot.offset().top + ($dot.height() / 2);
          var hypotenuse = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
          var angle = Math.atan2((y1 - y2), (x1 - x2)) *  (180 / Math.PI);

          if (angle >= 90 && angle < 180) {
              y1 = y1 - (y1 - y2);
          }
          if (angle > 0 && angle < 90) {
              x1 = x1 - (x1 - x2);
              y1 = y1 - (y1 - y2);
          }
          if (angle <= 0 && angle > -90) {
              x1 = x1 - (x1 - x2);
          }

          $line.queue(function() {
            //alert("drag");
              $(this).offset({top: y1, left: x1});
              $(this).dequeue();
          }).queue(function() {
              $(this).width(hypotenuse);
              $(this).dequeue();
          }).queue(function() {
              $(this).rotate(angle);
              $(this).dequeue();
          });

          marker.pos.x = parseInt($dot.css('left'));
          marker.pos.y = parseInt($dot.css('top'));
          // alert(marker.pos.x+"::"+marker.pos.y);
       };

    // var $title = $('<h2 class="image-marker__text-box__title" contenteditable="true">Title</h2>');
    // if (!!marker.title) $title.text(marker.title);
    // $title.on('change keydown paste input', function() {
    //   marker.title = $title.text();
    // });
    // $text_box.append($title);

    var $content = $('<p class="image-marker__text-box__content" contenteditable="true">Content</p>');
    if (!!marker.content) $content.text(marker.content);
    $content.on('change keydown paste input', function() {
      marker.content = $content.text();
    });
    $text_box.append($content);

    if (!!marker.className) {
      $text_box.addClass(marker.className);
      $dot.addClass(marker.className);
      $line.addClass(marker.className);
    }

    if (marker.col == 1) {
      return this.mountTo(this.$left_box, $text_box, $dot, $line, onDrag, marker);
    } else if (marker.col == 2) {
      return this.mountTo(this.$right_box, $text_box, $dot, $line, onDrag, marker);
    } else {
      if (this.mountTo(this.$left_box, $text_box, $dot, $line, onDrag, marker)) return marker.col = 1;
      if (this.mountTo(this.$right_box, $text_box, $dot, $line, onDrag, marker)) return marker.col = 2;
    }
  },

  mountTo: function($target, $text_box, $dot, $line, onDrag, marker) {

    // hidding element, but still displaying for future measurements
    $text_box.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
    $target.append($text_box);

    if ($target.height() > $target.parent().height()) {
      $text_box.remove();
      return false;
    }

    if (!this.settings.drag_disabled) {
      var $close_btn = $('<div class="image-marker__text-box__close-btn">X</div>');
      $close_btn.on('click', function() {
        var idx = this._markers.indexOf(marker);
        this._markers.splice(idx, 1);
        $text_box.remove();
        $dot.remove();
        $line.remove();
        this.$element.trigger('drag_all');
        this.$element.trigger('drag_all');
      }.bind(this));
      $text_box.append($close_btn);
    }

    $text_box.css({visibility: 'visible'});

    if (!marker.pos) {
      marker.pos = {
        x: ($text_box.parent()[0] == this.$left_box[0]) ? 0 : this.$drag_box.width() - 20,
        y: $text_box.offset().top - $text_box.parent().offset().top + $text_box.height() / 2 - 10
      };
    }

    $dot.css({top: marker.pos.y + 'px', left: marker.pos.x + 'px'});
    this.$drag_box.append($line).append($dot);

    $dot.draggable({
      containment: 'parent',
      distance: 0,
      delay: 0,
      disabled: this.settings.drag_disabled
    }, {
      drag: onDrag
    });

    this.$element.on('drag_all', onDrag);

    if (!this.settings.drag_disabled) $text_box.draggable({
      revert: true
    }, {
      start: function() {
        $dot.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
        $line.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
      },
      stop: function() {
        this.$element.trigger('drag_all');
        this.$element.trigger('drag_all');
        $dot.css({visibility: 'visible'});
        $line.css({visibility: 'visible'});
      }.bind(this)
    });

    $.data($text_box[0], 'marker', marker);

    onDrag();
    onDrag();

    // if case of success add to memory
    this._markers.push(marker);
    return true;
  }
});

$.fn[ pluginName ] = function( options ) {
  return this.each(function() {
    if ( !$.data( this, 'plugin_' + pluginName ) ) $.data( this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
  });
};

$.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
  $(this).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
  return $(this);
};

})( jQuery, window, document );

// todo: dot size
// todo: text_box order

// todo: remove $.fn.rotate
```

Comment: What kind of problem do you observe on the mobile device? What OS and browser are you using on the mobile device?

Comment: We can't drag line on touch screen. We are using it on chrome browser in mobile.